# Updating the UI after the background work completes in a coroutine

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I came across the following code sample that shows how to use a coroutine to run your background code on the IO thread and then switch to the UI (Main) thread when you need to update the UI:

```
class YourActivity : CoroutineScope {
    private lateinit var job: Job

    // context for io thread
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.IO + job

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    job = Job()
  }

    fun toDoSmth() {
        launch {
            // task, do smth in io thread
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
              // do smth in main thread after task is finished
            }                  
        }
    }

   override fun onDestroy() {
      job.cancel()
      super.onDestroy()
   }
}
```

Is this the correct way to update the UI after the background work has completed?

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the things are much easier. You shouldn't manage your own coroutine scope, take a look at [LifecycleScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope), it's already bound to the activity lifecycle. But the better way is to use [ViewModelScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) in conjunction with [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) library.

Note, that both `viewModelScope` and `lifecycleScope` use `Dispatchers.Main` by default, so you should pass IO dispatcher to the `launch` method, like:

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // task, do smth in io thread
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
      // do smth in main thread after task is finished
    }
}
```